# Getting: Could not detect any platform in the source directory. for Deploying React on Azure Static site

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-static-website-hosting

Im deploying on azure static web app but getting the error, which says:
Could not detect any platform in the source directory.
Error: Could not detect the language from repo.

i tried changing the app_location to /src but still showing could not detect the language from repo.

```
  # For more information regarding Static Web App workflow configurations, please visit: https://aka.ms/swaworkflowconfig
          app_location: "/src" # App source code path
          api_location: "" # Api source code path - optional
          output_location: "/build" # Built app content directory - optional
```

Comment: Could you check this [Github issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/mslearn-staticwebapp/issues/32) helps to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad @*Bhanuvidh Mansinghani*, that the given reference worked to resolve your issue.

I have found the similar issue from the GitHub of  [mslearn-staticwebapp](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/mslearn-staticwebapp/issues/32)  repository that states could not detect the language from repository in static web app workflow.

Many customers faced the similar issue and fixed with the following steps:

- Select the location and output folder for the application that is built for production environment and select custom option on step 5 instead of selecting the language.
- Now, redeploy it after making the changes to existing one.
- Also, check one of the workarounds given by the  [gcoines-uoc](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/mslearn-staticwebapp/issues/32#issuecomment-763863003)  that to check the path of the application’s folder within the .yml file and had given the project folder structure based on hierarchy levels.

Comment: Hi, could you explain how/where you do step 1?  I.e. where can you select the location of the output folder?